# Using yq to write to multiple wild card files?

Tags: bash, yq

Is it possible to do this in one line instead of doing this?

```
      yq eval '.image.tag = "${{ github.sha }}"' -i development-east-01.yaml
      yq eval '.image.tag = "${{ github.sha }}"' -i development-west-03.yaml
```

I tried using development-*.yaml
but it would only write to the first file and not all matching *

Comment: `for yaml in development-*.yaml ; do yq eval '.image.tag = "${{ github.sha }}"' -i "$yaml" ; done` may work. Save copys before testing! Good luck.

Comment: You can access individual files using `eval-all` and `select(fileIndex == 0)` but the `-i` flag only writes to the first one. See the docs: `-i, --inplace   update the yaml file inplace of first yaml file given.`. One day, yq might offer a `save` function (as there is a separate `load` function), but for now, the only way is to loop through the files in the calling environment, and execute yq individually for each one of them (see [shelter's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75610600/using-yq-to-write-to-multiple-wild-card-files#comment133395923_75610600)).

Answer (score 3):

yq doesn't have a built in way of updating multiple files, but your shell should have a built in mechanism of calling a command against matching files.

For instance in bash:

```
find development-*.yaml -exec yq '.image.tag = "${{ github.sha }}"' -i {} \;
```

Disclaimer: I wrote yq